# Optimize traversal and look up in gremlin query of connected components

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server, connected-components

I'm trying to find all the nodes in a connected component in a graph, which contains around ~130M vertices and ~350M edges.

Following is the query I'm using to find the count of nodes in connected components -

Input - starting vertex id/name

Output - count of nodes in the connected component.

Query - `g.v().has("name", "driver1").repeat(where(without ("a")).store("a").both().simplePath().dedup()).emit().hasLabel("driver").count().fold()`

The above query is taking around ~ 52 sec

RepeatStep is taking around ~ 29 sec

Is there a way we can optimize the linear traversal in Repeatstep or lookup in WherePredicateatep?

Profile output of above query-

```
"dur": 29008.200345, "counts": ("traverserCount": 13809,"elementCount": 13809}, name: "RepeatStep ([Where PredicateStep (without ([a])), Profilestep, Storestep (a), Profilestep, JanuaGraphVertexStep(BOTH, vertex), ProfileStep, PathFilterstep(simple), Profilestep, RepeatEndstep, Profilestep], until(false), emit(true))", "annotations":{ "percentDur": 52.557919400750215}, "id": "2.0.0()", "metrics": [ { "dur": 38.137699, "counts":{ traverserCount: 13810, elementCount: 13810}, "name":"WherePredicateStep(without([a]))", "id": "0.1.0 (2.0.0())" }, { "dur": 28628.594393, "counts": { "traverserCount": 252428, "elementCount": 252428 }, name: "JanusGraphVertexStep (BOTH, vertex)", "annotations"
```

Comment: It looks like a good discussion of the issue is taking place already in response to you asking here groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/x3HwF_Ocr5g

Comment: Yes, but I haven’t yet received any satisfactory response, so I thought of posting it here as well.

Comment: I'll add an answer but it's going to be similar t the ones posted in Gremlin-Users.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of graph queries comes down to the amount of data that needs to be touched and also the amount of help that the index(es) can give. The traverser  count in the profile result shows you how much data was touched (essentially the fan out of the query). If you are using JanusGraph a `.profile()` of your query will show you how much help (or not) the index is providing. If you are using Amazon Neptune, providing a label to steps like `both` and `in` helps the query engine take advantage of the available indexes. In some cases multi threading the query and joining the results in an application can help. In your case, without knowing the exact makeup of your data it is hard to give additional suggestions.